# how to write a kernel module to list all daemons

Tags: linux-kernel, daemon

Daemons are basically user processes which are re-parented to systemd (INIT). So, I traversed the task list with the following condition :

```
if ((task->flags & PF_KTHREAD)==0 && (task->parent->pid == 1))
```

It gives all daemons but also include processes that are not daemons.
So, is there some other way that will give me only daemons.

Comment: What non-daemon processes are listed? Are you sure that they are not daemons?

Answer (score 1):

init also adopts processes if their parent dies to wait on them, not sure how but you should check to see if the process is an orphan and ignore it.